# Is this argument sufficient to show alternating zeta series converges for $Re(s)>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series

The alternating zeta series

$$ \eta(s) = \sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} $$

is known to converge for $\sigma=\Re(s)>0$.

**Question:** There are many proofs offered but I wondered if the following simple (suitable for students pre-university) argument is correct and sufficient?

1. It is known that Dirichlet series have an abscissa of convergence $\sigma_c$, where the series converge for $\sigma>\sigma_c$.
2. This means we only need to find the convergence interval in the real domain.
3. In the real domain only, the alternating zeta series $\eta(\sigma)$, converges for $\sigma>0$.
4. Therefore, the alternating zeta series $\eta(s)$ converges for $\Re(s)>0$ in the complain domain.

Comment: How do you prove that Dirichlet series have an abcissa of  convergence?

Comment: Hi @vonbrand the proofs than an abscissa of convergence given in many textbooks including Apostol don't seem to require university level background knowledge. Have I missed something important as I don't think that is relevant to this question? I could be wrong....